# Create app that launches a local app in Joli OS

Tags: chrome, application, javascript

Recently (I mean, for the last 30 minutes) I have been playing with Joli OS. I spent quite a bit of time trying to figure out how local apps are launched within the web browser. After figuring out that it uses websockets and finding the JS function (`jolios.system.apps.launch("command-goes-here")`), I tried to create an "app" (using the button in the app store) that launches Nautilus. Entering the URL `javascript:jolios.system.apps.launch("nautilus ~")` doesn't work.

Is there another way to do this?